# Change font-size in primeng datatables in angular2 project

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I am trying to adjust the font-size of the column headers and may be the content as well. I tried to do a pure css solution based on the structural classes mentioned by Primeng here, but to no avail.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/theming

I looked at other stackoverflow but found this way to be the accepted answer.

```
<p-column field="type" header="Type"
        [style]="{'text-align': 'center', 'font-size': '0.8em'}"></p-column>
```

Is there a pure css way to modify font size of primeng datatables and other components using pure css solutions.

Worth mentioning that I am not really a UI/UX person. So if someone has already solved this I would be grateful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You can solve it in two ways.

Priming Datatable can be styled using style attribute **styleClass** or **tableStyleClass**

Example:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" tableStyleClass="prime-table">
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin" styleClass="pr-column1"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year" styleClass="pr-column2"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand" styleClass="pr-column3"></p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color" styleClass="pr-column4"></p-column>. 
</p-dataTable>
```

You can give respective style class to this attributes.

The second way of editing the style is please refer https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table

The bottom part Styling header. Here you can get the styling elements of the datatable. Write your customized style to those elements and it will work for you.

Example:

```
.ui-datatable-header{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Hope these two will help you to sort the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The PrimeNG datatable is basically an HTML table so you can change it by just using `td` and `th` to change `font-size` for the cells, headers or both.

```
th, td {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

However, if you want to change styles through CSS for the whole table easily, you can use the `tableStyleClass` property and just create a new class for the table like this:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" tableStyleClass="prime-table">
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

And add the styling to the class:

```
 .prime-table{
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 0.8em;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, both the solutions are not working, th td one as well as the tableStyleClass one. The tableStyleClass is one of their attributes for styling the table. Ideally your solution should work. But somehow its not working me. If it is working for someone else then this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but I've also not included any PrimeUI theme and styled all the elements myself. Maybe it gets overridden by something in your CSS. You can try using an `!important` rule to see if that's the case or it's something else.

Comment: I think you need `/deep/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to suit your needs

```
.ui-table,
.ui-table .ui-table-wrapper table {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

`ui-table`, and `ui-table-wrapper` are css classes defined in the latest version of tables of PrimeNG